# document.getElementByID - checking whether an element has been found or not

Tags: html, dom, scripting, vbscript

Here's a sample code, that opens an internet explorer window, navigates to google, and gets some element on the page by its unique id:

```
set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

ie.navigate("www.google.com")
ie.visible = true

while ie.readystate <> 4
    wscript.sleep 100
WEnd

set some_object = ie.document.getelementbyid("xjsc")

MsgBox some_object.tagname, 0
```

This sample brings me a `DIV` popup, which satisfies me completely.

But at the next step I'd like to check whether some id exists in the page, or not. Unfortunately, I can't just be, like,

```
set some_object = ie.document.getelementbyid("some_non_existant_id")
if some_object.tagname = "" then
...
```

because it gives me the following error:

```
ie.vbs(12, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object required: 'some_object'
```

So, what's the best practice to check whether an element has been found or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if isObject(some_object) then
```

if the variable holds an object then it was found ...

***[update]***
After some tests and some comments, you need to use the `isNothing` method..

since you are setting an object it will always be an object variable type, but if it is not found it is set to nothing ..

```
if isNothing(some_object) then
```

I have checked the above with your sample code, and it works as expected..

in vbscript terms it would be

```
if some_object is nothing then
```

Comment: yeah, but it retruns `true` for me in BOTH cases, even when nothing was found!

Comment: @be here now, check out `isNull` (or even `isEmpty`). According to specs, it returns null if nothing is found..

Comment: I did, they all seem to output false regardless the element has been found or not.

Comment: Things are getting weird.... 

`D:\work\_tmp\ie.vbs(12, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Type mismatch: 'isnothing'`

By the way, isNothing is a VB6 function, isn't it? I havent found it in VBScript refs.

Comment: @be here now, you are right .. i was thinking in terms of vb.. vbscript equivalent is `if some_object is nothing then`